# How to show multi Flat List inside the same screen with scrolling

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to show more then one flat list horizontal and scroll vertically from one to another.
I did it by insert all the 3 flat list inside a scroll View but I understood it is a bad practice and getting the warning- "VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead."

'''

export default function Recommendation() {

```
return (
  <View style={{marginTop: 25}}>
      <ScrollView   showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} >
        <Carousel data = {DataForCarousel}/>
        <Category />  
        <Deal />   
      </ScrollView>
  </View>
);
```

}

'''

Carousel- horizontal FlatList

Category- horizontal FlatList

Deal - vertically FlatList